# How to represent a 3-tier architecture in UML?

Tags: .net, architecture, uml, winapp

I have an windows application developed, and I need to document its architecture. I made a 3-tier diagram according to Microsoft Practices and Patterns, but my chief wants a representation made from UML's perspective.

How do you represent a 3-tier diagram on UML?

PS: The three tiers are basically, a presentation layer, business layer and data access layer. Just in case.

Comment: It depends on the level of detail you want to show. do you want to only show the three tiers and their high level relationships? do you have several packages inside each tier that you want to show in the diagram? or do you want to show the classes you have in each tier and their relationships?

Comment: I want to show the class libraries inside each tier. And each tier relating to each other by dependency between each other. Just to put in a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UML package diagrams. For a similar example please see this link. Specifically the "Multi-Layered Web Architecture" part.

http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stereotypes](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile-diagrams.html) to note the classes in each one of the tiers. Check out [this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/0816_Louis/) (towards the middle of the article)